# How to check if a list contains the term in NEST?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have the query shown below:

```
var queryResult =
    await
        elastic.SearchAsync<CounterData>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(
                        m => m.ConstantScore(c => c
                            .Filter(f => f
                                .Term(x =>  x.CounterId, maxList))
                            ),
                        m => m.ConstantScore(c => c.
                            Filter(f => f
                                .Term(x => x.Type, counterType))),
                        m => m.ConstantScore(c => c.
                            Filter(f => f.
                                DateRange(d => d.
                                    GreaterThanOrEquals(lowerBound).Field(r => r.Date)))))))
            .AllTypes()
            .Scroll("1m")
            .Size(10000));
```

Where `maxList` is a list of integers. I want to check if the term is in the list but looks like this does not work.

Any ideas how I can check if the term matches any of the elements in the list?

Comment: Can't you do  f.Contains(x.CounterId)?

Comment: @JeroenDop Well there is no `contains` for `f` and if I do `maxList.Contains(x.CounterId)` I get a syntax error

Comment: is there a specific reason for using `constant_score` queries?

Comment: @RussCam I am just querying data and don't do anything related to score (nor I want the scores to alter my search) so I thought it would be a good idea based on the examples I have seen (I am a noob yes :))

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following will do it

```
var maxList = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var counterType = "counter-type";
var lowerBound = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-7);

var queryResult = client.Search<CounterData>(s => s
    .Query(q => +q
        .DateRange(d => d
            .Field(r => r.Date)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(lowerBound)
        ) && +q
        .Term(x => x.Type, counterType) && +q
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(x => x.CounterId)
            .Terms(maxList)
        )
    )
    .AllTypes()
    .Scroll("1m")
    .Size(10000)
);
```

A few things to highlight

- `+` unary operator applied to a `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>` is a shorthand for wrapping a query in a `bool` `filter` query. I think this is what you want in your case as you don't need to calculate scores, you just want to find matches to a predicate.
- `&&` is overloaded for `QueryContainer` such that when applied to two `QueryContainer`s, it is a shorthand for a `bool` `must` query with two must query clauses. However in this example, the queries all have the `+` unary operator applied so are `bool` `filter` queries, so will be `&&`'ed together as filter queries.
- The value passed to `Size()` when using Scrolling (i.e. specifying a `Scroll()` time) is the number of documents to fetch from **each shard** per scroll, not total documents per scroll. So total documents will be `Size() * number of shards`. This might be a lot of documents per scroll.
- Use the [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to find documents that match on a field against any one of a list of terms (not analyzed).

The end query json looks like

```
POST http://localhost:9200/examples/_search?scroll=1m 
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2016-08-04T00:00:00Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "type": {
              "value": "counter-type"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "counterId": [
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```